# FInd a control after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, postback, web-controls

I have at table which is dynamically created at postback; its a list of documents with a standard html checkbox which for each row. The aim is to be able to select & download multiple documents in 1 click.

The problem I am having is I cannot access any of the checkbox's my guess is they are not in the viewstate because they were not created onLoad or onInit.

Ok so a client selects their document category & clicks the get documents button. That then hits the database and creates the html rows including the checkboxes. The HTML is then loaded into a literal sitting between the  tags.

**Update**

Ok so I'm not using  and have created the rows and cells via the code behind. I can now see the checkboxes in the Conrol Tree via Trace.

> ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$639eec32-f1a8-4fbb-a442-d429571fc3a5   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox

This is what I've tried to find the checkboxes:

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control Root, string Id) { 
    if (Root.ID == Id) return Root; 
    foreach (Control Ctl in Root.Controls) { 
        Control FoundCtl = FindControlRecursive(Ctl, Id); 
        if (FoundCtl != null) return FoundCtl; 
    } 
    return null;
}
```

When the FindControlRecursive function runs; it only sees 5 controls on the page; have I done enough to find the checked checkboxes or am I still not going in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm also using the 'trace' functionality and none of the controls show up there.

Comment: Could you just add runat='server' to the checkboxes?

Comment: You should show us how (and where) you've created the CheckBoxes.

Comment: show some code, in which events are you creating this controls and in which other events are you trying to find and use those after a postback?

Comment: They have runat="server" assigned to them; but they cant be seen by the viewstate.

Comment: Btw, the only way to download multiple files in one request is to zip them.

Comment: They are just normal html checkboxs; created in a html string using StringBuilder.

Comment: using this to find them:

`public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control Root, string Id)
    {
        if (Root.ID == Id)

            return Root;

        foreach (Control Ctl in Root.Controls)
        {
            Control FoundCtl = FindControlRecursive(Ctl, Id);

            if (FoundCtl != null)

                return FoundCtl;
        }
        return null;
    }`

Comment: Yep using the Ionic.Zip library

Comment: @bExplosion: Add this code to your question instead of a comment.Edit: _done_.

Comment: Give them a name and request their values with good old Request.Form["somename"]

Comment: @bExplosion: You cannot add a HTML-String, append a `runat=server` and hope that ASP.NET will care of them. You must add them to the page's ControlCollection to get ViewState and events or to find them via `FindControl(id)`.

Comment: Damn that was my first initial thought; I was just wondering if there was another way.

If I have a <table runat="server"></table>

Then add the rows & columns programmatically will that attach them to the ViewState @ postback?

Comment: Yes, if their added as [HtmlTableRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltablerow.aspx) and not as string. The same for HtmlTableCells and [HtmlInputCheckbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputcheckbox%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). But remember to add them on every postback in page's load event at the latest with the same ID as before. Btw, why not simply use f.e. a GridView or Repeater?

Answer (score 1):

It is not the issue of searching controls. You need just add them properly at every request at OnInit phase.

Don't use Literal control to add ASP.NET server controls. Use special containers like PlaceHolder instead.

Then, if you know the Id of control you can simply use FindControl():

```
Control myControl1 = FindControl("TextBox2");
```

Comment: Seeing I know the names of the controls; how do I add them to Oninit?

Comment: you need to restore previous state of the page to handle next request. Since category of files have been chosen at previous request, you can save its value in Session for example and recreate everything on OnInit during postback.

Comment: @pukipuki: -1 Does not show how to create html controls dynamically that are added as string and reference them in codebehind(what is impossible) and does not show an alternative way(f.e. adding HtmlInputCheckboxes to a Panel).

Comment: Yes, Missed that he adds them into Literal as plain text... or maybe he added that info later )

Answer (score 1):

Make sure they are being created as you mentioned. You can either use the IE Developer tool (F12) or page source and check their ID's. Then you should be able to use FindControl(). You would probly have to cast it to a CheckBox control so you can check if its checked or unchecked...